# How to retrieve Hash Password in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, encryption, pbkdf2, password-hash

What is the proper way to **retrieve / reset password / Forgot Password** ?

I used Password Based Key Derivation Function 2 (PBKDF2) in the Rfc2898DeriveBytes class.

```
   public static string HashPassword(string password)
        {
            if (password == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
            }

            byte[] salt;
            byte[] subkey;
            using (var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SaltSize, Pbkdf2Count))
            {
                salt = deriveBytes.Salt;
                subkey = deriveBytes.GetBytes(Pbkdf2SubkeyLength);
            }

            byte[] outputBytes = new byte[1 + SaltSize + Pbkdf2SubkeyLength];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, outputBytes, 1, SaltSize);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(subkey, 0, outputBytes, 1 + SaltSize, Pbkdf2SubkeyLength);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(outputBytes);
        }
```

So what is the way to reset hash password.

Comment: Please stop and think and state _precisely_ what you're trying to do in a step by step manner.

Comment: @SLaks: Want to retrieve password, Asking for Decryption process

Comment: It must **never** be possible to retrieve a password.  You need to verify the user's identity and create a new password.

Comment: Your code is broken; you need to store the length of the salt.